# Vue router: How to update Store using <router-link> before it navigates. <router-link> navigates before Store updates

Tags: vue.js

I am new in `Vue`. I have installed `Vuex` and `view-router` in my `Laravel` application. The `view-router` and `router-link` are working as desired.

However, I want to put the item object in `Vue store` when a `router-link` is clicked so that I can retrieve it in the detail view and show required data there.

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
   <div v-for="item in featuredItems" :key="item.id">
      <router-link :title="item. name" :to="productUrl(item)">
        ...
      </router-link>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   data() {
     return {
        featuredItems: [...]
     }
   },
   methods: {
      productUrl(item) {
         store.state.selectedProdcut = item;
         return '/product/' + item.slug;
      }
   }
</script>
```

**Product.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="text-2xl text-green-800">
        {{ currentItem.name }} <br />
        <img :src="currentItem.photo" alt="" />
        Product slug is: {{ $route.params.productSlug }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "../../store";

export default {
    name: "Product",
    data() {
        return {
            currentItem: {}
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.currentItem = this.getItem;
    },
    computed: {
        getItem() {
            return store.state.selectedProdcut;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

**Store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        selectedProdcut: {}
    },
    mutations: {},
    actions: {}
});
```

**Problem:**

If I put try to save current item in store inside `productUrl` method, which is called by `:to` attribute of `router-link`, console says an indefinite loop is being created.
However, if I add a `@click` attribute to the loop, i.e.

```
<div @click="storeSelectedProduct(item)" v-for="item in featuredItems" :key="item.id">
  <router-link to="productUrl(item)">...</router-link>
</div>
```

The item is saved in Store and I get it back in the next page. But this is not the way I want this to work. I want to click the `router-link` and store the object in Store. I don't want the container `div` to have a `@click` attribute separately to handle the Storing!

What is the correct way to update `Vuex Store` using `<router-link>`?

**UPDATE:**
I did a mistake by not exporting the store in `app.js`. Now I can access `this.$store` object, which I was unable to access before.

Now I can use the following method with `<router-link :to="productUrl(item)">`

```
methods: {
   productUrl(item) {
       this.$store.state.selectedProdcut = item;
       return "/product/" + item.slug;
   }
},
```

However, the problem now is the last item is only getting added to Store, which is quite understandable. In short, I want the store to be updated when I click on a `<router-link>`, but before navigating, the store would get updated with the `item` I am passing. Is this possible?

Comment: If storing the item and then getting it back in the next (supposedly the details) page is not what you want - then what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. I exactly want that to happen. Storing `item` in one component and get it back in another. Probably "**The item is saved in stored and I get it back in the next page. But this is not what I want.**" has confused. I wanted to say that I do not want the container to use a `@click` attribute. I want to store it from `router-link` only. I have updated my question.

Comment: Visiting the Detail view from the address bar directly will mean no item will be set.  This illustrates one of the shortcomings of mixing state mutation with route clicks.  The detail page should get the information from the slug alone.  Also you are mutating the store  in your component instead of using a Vuex [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)

Comment: Hi @Dan I am very new to Vue. You are absolutely right that "The detail page should get the information from the slug alone". Right now I am using a static object for product list. In real time, I will use axios/fetch to get the item from the database based on the slug only. "**Also you are mutating the store state in your component instead of using a Vuex mutation**" - would you please explain this a bit?

Comment: `this.$store.state.selectedProdcut = item;` this is not allowed, see the link in my previous comment.  It should be like `this.$store.commit('setSelected', item)` to commit a mutation from the component.  Or for an action, `this.$store.dispatch('setSelected', item)`

Comment: I am going through the article. Thank you @Dan

Comment: You can use the `beforeRouteLeave` navigation guard (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to trigger the mutation but as Dan said - there are caveats.